# Text input doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, input, contacts

I have a problem with my website and I don't get it why it doesn't work.

I have two separate domains with the same WordPress theme (http://takoplius.lt and http://takoplius.ru). The interesting thing when I load pages on Chrome browser .lt version contact form inputs are not working, but in .ru version, everything works just fine with contact form and I can type text in inputs. When I try to load the .lt page in Firefox, contact form works just fine there.

Here is my form code:

```
<form method="post" id="kontaktu_forma" onsubmit="send_email('<?=$lang;?>'); return false;">
        <label><?=$vardas_pavarde;?>: </label>
        <input class="input" type="text"  name="vardas" />

        <label><?=$imones_pavadinimas;?>: </label>
        <input class="input" type="text"  name="imone" />

        <label><?=$adresas_aa;?>: </label>
        <input class="input" type="text"  name="adresas" />

        <label><?=$telefono_nr;?>: </label>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="phone" />


        <label><?=$el_pastas;?>: </label>
        <input class="input" type="text"  name="email" />


        <label><?=$dominancios_paslaugos;?>:</label>
        <textarea class="input" rows="5" name="klausimas"></textarea>    

        <input type="button" class="button" value="<?=$siusti;?>" onclick="send_email('<?=$lang;?>'); return false;" style="margin-left: 15px;" />
    </form>
```

It would be great if someone helps me with this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to change this

```
jQuery(function($) {        

    $('body').disableTextSelect();

 });
```

To

```
jQuery(function($) {          

            $('#main').disableTextSelect();

    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me. Now text inputs are working and I can fill the form.

Answer (score 0):

not only your input selection is disables but you cant select any text from that website

because your are disabling text selection from js, I found below code in your website, you remove this code and it will fix your problem

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $('body').disableTextSelect();
});
```

just remove or comment out above code.